# Nothing happens when using command

Tags: discord.js

I am having some problems to run this commands: the export does work fine (no issues at console log) but when I execute some of those commands nothing happens...

```js
let _exports = require("../exports.js");

module.exports.main = function(guild,command,type,member,message) {

  const Discord = require('discord.js');
  const prefix = "!"

    Client.on("ready", () => {
        console.log("online");
        Client.user.setPresence({ game: { name: `Hello world`, type: 0} });
    });

    // welcome message

    Client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
       member.guild.defaultChannel.send("Welcome to: " + member.guild.name + "")
    });

    Client.on("guildMemberRemove", member => {
       member.guild.defaultChannel.send("Goodbye: " + member.user.username + " from " + member.guild.name)
    });

    Client.on("guildCreate", guild => {
        console.log("server owner: " + guild.owner.user.username)
    });

    Client.on("message", async (message) => {
        if (message.author.bot) return;
        if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

        let command = message.content.split(" ")[0];
        command = command.slice(prefix.length);

        let args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1);

        if (command === "ping") {
            message.channel.send(`Pong! Time took: ${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp} ms`);
        } else

        if (command === "say") {
            message.delete()
            const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor(0x954D23)
            .setDescription(message.author.username + " says: " + args.join(" "));
            message.channel.send({embed})
        } else

        if (command == "helpz") {
            const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor(0x954D23)
            .setTitle("Command List:")
            .addField("!help", "Will give the current command list")
            .addField("!ping", "WIll show the ping time for the bot")
            .addField("!say [text]", "Will make the bot say something")
            message.channel.send({embed})
        }

        if(command === `slive`){

          let botembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
          .setColor("#C02909")
          .addField("**LIVE, ALL!**", ("good luck!"));

          return message.channel.send('@here', botembed);

        }

        if(command === `sremake`){

          let botembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
          .setColor("#C02909")
          .addField("**RMK / ALL!**", ("rmk"));

          return message.channel.send('@here', botembed);

        }

        if(command === `cd15s`){

          let botembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
          .setColor("#C02909")
          .addField("Next lobby starts in **15** Seconds", ("00:15"));


          return message.channel.send('@here', botembed);

        }

        if(command === `cd30s`){

          let botembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
          .setColor("#C02909")
          .addField("Next lobby starts in **30** Seconds", ("00:30"));

          return message.channel.send('@here', botembed);return message.channel.send('@here', botembed);

        }

        if(command === `cd1m`){

          let botembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
          .setColor("#C02909")
          .addField("Next lobby starts in **1** Minute", ("01:00"));

          return message.channel.send('@here', botembed);return message.channel.send('@here', botembed);

        }

        if(command === `cd2m`){

          let botembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
          .setColor("#C02909")
          .addField("Next lobby starts in **2** Minutes", ("02:00"));

          return message.channel.send('@here', botembed);
        }

    });
  };
```

If you know where the issue is just modify the source! thank you beforehand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's your entire file, that can't work because `Client` is not defined: you could either pass the client as an argument to the `module.exports.main` function, or declare it at the top.
With that said, I won't export all that stuff: since you're declaring only event listeners, you can directly add them in the same function where you declared the client. Exporting can be useful only if you want to keep every command in a different file (you could also use [`discord.js-commando`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/commando/master/general/welcome)). In that case, you should declare the listeners in the main file, then require the command files.
Scheme:

```js
// main file
const Discord = require('discord');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready') {...}
// other "client.on"s
client.on('message') {
  // command parsing & co
  if (command == 'say') require('./commands/say.js').main()
}
```

```js
// command file: '/commands/say.js'
module.exports.main = (message, ...args) => {
  ...
};
```